# How to add new lines in item's description in Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to have multi-line description for the items in the Stripe Checkout. However, Stripe trims all white spaces in the description, including new lines.

For example, instead of:

```
First name: John
Last name: Doe
Email: example@gmail.com
```

Description ends up looking like this:

```
First name: John Last name: Doe Email: example@gmail.com
```

This example is only for question purposes. I will have a little more complex use case than this. Is it possible to override this behavior and apply formatting to description, or at lease keep the new lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with Stripe Support. This is not possible with Stripe Checkout at the moment:

> We don't see this being possible to do with Stripe Checkout. We can't guarantee that this feature will be implemented at the moment, but we’re rapidly evolving our product suites, so be sure to stay close to hear about new products and features as we announce them.